# Can I Create iOS Application for Clients Using Personal Apple Developer Account?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

sorry if this is a stupid question, but I have been searching online and not finding exact answers to my question.

I am building newsstand applications for myself and would like to help other people get started with their own newsstand applications. I have a personal developer account and so do the people I would like to help.

My question is:
Is it possible for me to setup the app in Xcode, iTunes Connect & Apple Developer Account and then transfer the app to the people I want to help?

I am not sure Apple allows this with personal developer accounts? If it's allowed and possible, what are the best practices for this? Is there any way to "share" provisioning profiles, or will the people I help have to setup all that themselves?

Ideally I would love to help with setting up:
apple ID (developer account)
profiles (developer account)
newsstand app (iTunes Connect)
in app purchases (iTunes Connect)

If at all possible, I would love to be able to publish for a client, but I think that is not possible with only personal developer accounts?

Sorry if this is all newbie stuff, links to documentation would be great! I am fine doing all these things myself, but lately people have been asking me to help out and this is where it's getting a little tricky for me.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  This was added under (or, I think, a month or two before) the iOS 7 release, and is fairly new.

You can find out how to do it here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/10_ManagingYourApplications/ManagingYourApplications.html

Under "transferring your apps".  There is a button "transfer app" on the app summary page.